# include_once(db-config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I am facing error while creating a user login and registration page. Here is my code. Error screenshot is attached.

**db-config.php**

```
<?php 
define("HOST", "localhost"); 
define("USER", "sec_user");
define("PASSWORD", "eKcGZr59zAa2BEWU");
define("DATABASE", "sumerian");
?>
```

**db-connection.php**

```
<?php
include_once("db‐config.php"); // As functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db-connection.php';
include_once 'php-functions.php';
sec_session_start(); //function for session
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) 
{
    $logged = 'in';
} 
else 
{
   $logged = 'out';
}
?>
//html content goes here
```

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a character encoding problem.
The `-` in your file name is interpreted by php as `á€`.
Are all your files UTF-8 encoded?

Quick fix would be to remove the `-` from your file names and test it.

But if your character encoding on the html or http level differs from your application-level/file encoding or your db connection/table encoding you have a completely different problem.

Comment: The - sign in the file name is not the standard symbol. Change the file name and be sure to type the - sign. It looks like it's pasted from a word file

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped. It was a problem with character encoding.